# How to solve this Python exception: local variable 'article' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, exception

I've the following code:

```
def id_to_article(id):
    if id == 1:
        article = "article: local"
    elif id == 2:
        article = "comments(article)"
    elif id == 3:
        article = "students"
    elif id == 4:
        ....
    elif id == 18:
        article = "community news"

    return article
```

I only call `id_to_article` with ID 1 to 18. However I get exception:

```
local variable 'article' referenced before assignment
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your statement is probably not correct.  Print `id` and `type(id)` before the first `if` statement to see what you're *really* passing in.

Comment: @LarryLustig I only `print id` and it was 1 to 18 always. What is `type(id)` about?

Comment: @LarryLustig I just printing `type(id)` it - `<type 'unicode'>`... What it means?

Comment: To determine whether you are passing a string or floating point number instead of an integer.

Comment: See -- you're not passing `1`, you're passing `"1"` (or `u"1"` if you're using Python 2.x).

Comment: Wow I see now. I'm using Python 2.2.3. Thanks. I will change 1 to "1", 2 to "2", ..., 18 to "18". Can you leave answer so I can upvote you and accept answer?

Comment: Probably you got that value via `input()` or something similar?  You need to convert it to type `integer` first, using `int()`.

Comment: It came in from a POST request in webapp. I didn't know 1 and "1" were not equal in Psython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that you're not, in fact, passing in an integer number from 1 to 18 but something else.  Try printing `id` and `type(id)` before the first if statement to see what's *really* arriving in your function.

Comment: This is the right answer. Turned out that 1 and "1" are surprisingly not equal values in Psython. If someone has this problem then you need to quote all numbers to solve it. Alternatively wrap it in `int()` call. Thanks!

Comment: There are very few programming languages that would equate `1` and `"1"`.  Many languages would type check the argument in the function definition (you would have to write `def id_to_article(integer id)` and would not be allowed to pass a string) but Python does not work this way.

Comment: Very interesting. I still have to lot to learn about Psython.

Answer (score 0):

`article` may not be set before you get to the `return` statement.  This could be resolved by initializing it before your sequence of if statements.

Comment: Are variables local to `if` blocks in Psython?

Comment: I added `print id`, and it's always in range 1 to 18 so it cant be uninitialized when it reaches `return`ing statement.

Comment: Python cannot know that; besides, if this function were used in other circumstances, it *could* have a value for `id` which results in `article` not getting assigned to.